# How to properly convert HashMap<String,List<Object>> to Json with array of json object

Tags: java, json, api, apache-kafka

I have a stream of Kafka messages and wanted to build a `HashMap<String,List<Object>>` to be used as API response in Json format.

```
for (ConsumerRecord<String,String> consumerRecord : records) {
    if(!responses.containsKey(consumerRecord.topic())){
        responses.put(consumerRecord.topic(), new ArrayList<Object>());
    }
    responses.get(consumerRecord.topic()).add(JSONObject.stringToValue(consumerRecord.value()));
}
```

expected response:

```
{
    "topic1": [
        {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3"}
    ],
    "topic2": [
        {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3"},
        {"anotherfield1":"anothervalue1","anotherfield2":"anothervalue2"}
    ]
}
```

actual response:

```
{
    "topic1": [
        "{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"value3\"}"
    ],
    "topic2": [
        "{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"value3\"}",
        "{\"anotherfield1\":\"anothervalue1\",\"anotherfield2\":\"anothervalue2\"}"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working using these changes:

```
HashMap<String,List<Object>> responses = new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();

for (ConsumerRecord<String,String> consumerRecord : records) {
    if(!responses.containsKey(consumerRecord.topic())){
        responses.put(consumerRecord.topic(), new ArrayList<Object>());
    }
    responses.get(consumerRecord.topic()).add(new JSONObject(consumerRecord.value()));
}

jsonObject = new JSONObject(responses);
return jsonObject.toMap();
```

1. Convert Kafka message string to JSONObject `new JSONObject(consumerRecord.value())`
2. Construct a JSONObject from a Map using
   `jsonObject = new JSONObject(responses);`
3. Return Map<String, Object> using `jsonObject.toMap();`

Comment: You can refactor `new JSONObject(consumerRecord.value())` if you setup the deserializer properly

Answer (score 1):

Slash quote (") symbol is just a properly escaped quotation in JSON. Your parser didn't recognize internal JSONs as JSONs but took them as Strings. Therefore within a String it escaped all " symbols. I suggest that you can use class [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) of [Json-Jackson (also known as Faster XML) library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (Maven artifacts [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind)). I wrote my own open source library called MgntUtils, that has JSON parser based on Json-Jackson. Using this library you can easily parse your JSON String into a Map

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = null;
try {
      myMap = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonString, Map.class);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
}
```

Here is Javadoc for [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The Maven artifacts for MgntUtils library could be found [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils), and library as a jar along with Javadoc and source code could be found on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)

Comment: Will try that one. for now I'll stick to my answer as it also resolved my problem. Thank you.